# JavaScript - replace word if it occurs otherwise append text to the end of a string

Tags: javascript, url, replace, append

I have this script to replace a word:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
window.location = url.replace(/(\?sort=name|size)/, 'date');
```

and this one meant to append a text to the end of a string:

```
var orig = location.href;
location.replace(orig+'?sort=date');
```

How to combine them into one script so the text only gets appended when the ?sort parameter isn't already there?

The ?sort parameter is supposed to be always at the end of a string, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.toString();
var re = /(\?sort=name|size)/;
window.location = re.test(url) ? url.replace(re, 'date') : url + "?sort=date";
```

Side note: I think you meant `'?sort=date'` instead of just `'date'` in your replace?

So `window.location = re.test(url) ? url.replace(re, '?sort=date') : url + "?sort=date";`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I kinda have some weird results with the replacing - if I put '?sort=date' it will result in '?sort=?sort=date' if the original was '?sort=size'. Works correctly with '?sort=name' as the original. With your script I have to use '?sort=date' but I also have to change the replacing to /(\?sort=name|\?sort=size)/. I don't really know how this works.

Comment: @user2044638 You probably just want `/\?sort=(name|size|date)/` which lets you put in all the various options, or even `\?sort=\w$` which matches `?sort=word` for any word so long as it's at the end of the line.

Comment: Yes! Thanks about that, too. I didn't know how to phrase that all the words supposed to be replaced have the same string in front of them.